# glm giving different results in R 3.2.0 and R 3.2.2. Was there any substantial change in usage?

Tags: r, glm

I use glm monthly to calculate a binomial model on the payment behaviour of a credit database, using a call like:

`modelx =  glm(paid ~ ., data = credit_db, family = binomial())`

For the last month, I use R version 3.2.2 (just recently upgraded) and the results were very different than the previous month (done with R version 3.2.0).  In order to check the code, I repeated the previous month calculations with version 3.2.2 and got different results from the previous calculation done in R 3.2.0.

Coefficients are also very different, in a wild form.  I use at the beginning an exploratory model, with a variable that is the average number of delinquency days during the month, which should yield low coefficients for low average.  In version 3.2.0, an extract of `summary(modelx)` was:

```
## Coefficients:                              Estimate Std. Error z value
## delinquency_avg_days1                      -0.59329    0.18581  -3.193
## delinquency_avg_days2                      -1.32286    0.19830  -6.671
## delinquency_avg_days3                      -1.47359    0.21986  -6.702
## delinquency_avg_days4                      -1.64158    0.21653  -7.581
## delinquency_avg_days5                      -2.56311    0.25234 -10.158
## delinquency_avg_days6                      -2.59042    0.25886 -10.007
```

and for version 3.2.2

```
## Coefficients                             Estimate   Std. Error z value
## delinquency_avg_days.L                  -1.320e+01  1.083e+03  -0.012  
## delinquency_avg_days.Q                  -1.140e+00  1.169e+03  -0.001
## delinquency_avg_days.C                   3.439e+00  1.118e+03   0.003
## delinquency_avg_days^4                   8.454e+00  1.020e+03   0.008  
## delinquency_avg_days^5                   3.733e+00  9.362e+02   0.004     
## delinquency_avg_days^6                  -4.988e+00  9.348e+02  -0.005
```

The summary output is a little different, since the `Pr(>|z|)` is shown.  Notice also that the coefficient names changed too.

In the dataset this delinquency_avg_days variable have the following distribution (0 is "not paid", 1 is "paid", and as you can see, coefficients might be large for average days larger than 20 or so.  Number of paid was sampled to match closely the number of "not paid".

```
     0   1
  0  140 663
  1   59 209
  2   62 118
  3   56  87
  4   66  50
  5   69  41
  6   64  40
  7   78  30
  8   75  31
  9   70  29
  10  77  23
  11  69  18
  12  79  17
  13  61  13
  14  53   5
  15  67  18
  16  50  10
  17  40   9
  18  39   8
  19  23   9
  20  24   2
  21  36   9
  22  35   1
  23  17   0
  24  11   0
  25  11   0
  26   7   1
  27   3   0
  28   0   0
  29   0   1
  30   1   0
```

In previous months, I used this exploratory model to create a second binomial model using ranges af average delinquency days.  But this other model gives similar results with a few levels.

Now, I'd like to know whether there are substantial changes that require specifying other parameters or there is an issue with glm in version 3.2.2.

Comment: It looks like `delinquency_avg_days` is an unordered factor in the `3.2.0` model and an ordered factor in the `3.2.2` model.

Comment: The data is different (which is causing the contrasts to be different), despite your claims to the contrary.

Comment: It is a possibility, since I don't have the same version, I can't generate the same train and test datasets I did before, and haven't save the data from the models before, then I can't compare.  Still the coefficients are very different.

Comment: delinquency_avg_days is an ordered factor in both cases.